# How to say in English that someone is aggressive and that aggression is pointed at someone?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-choice

What is the most natural way to say that someone is aggressive and that aggression is pointed at someone? Is any of the following options correct and natural?

> Kate is **aggressive to/towards** her Mom because she doesn't allow her to watch too much TV.
>
> Kate **behaves aggressively to/towards** her Mom because she doesn't allow her to watch too much TV.
>
> Kate is **aggressive with** her Mom because she doesn't allow her to watch too much TV.

Answer (score 1):

*To* and *towards* are not interchangeable in this scenario. The first two sentences should use *towards*, but other than that they are perfectly correct grammar-wise.

Whether or not they feel natural will depend on who is speaking. I would expect "Kate behaves aggressively towards her mom" to be used in a more formal context than "Kate is aggressive with her mom".

"Kate frequently lashes out at her mom" is another alternative that sounds more likely to be used informally.

Answer (score 0):

All three are perfectly acceptable, though the context may make one feel more natural than the others.
(Although, at the moment, No.2 needs to match No.1, (it is missing `because she`) and in No.3 `to` should read `too`